# Laravel - How to check user is allowed to access the branch/location while login

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to create a location based login page in Laravel 8.

Admin will add many locations for the user (will store in user_locations table), and Admin can make the location mapping active/inactive for the particular user, but can't delete the location.

Using this, I need to allow the user to login into the particular location.

But, I am not sure how to validate the user and throw error if the user is not authenticated to access the particular location.

I am getting 3 inputs from the user that is user_id, password, and sub_location_id.

Once getting all the details, we need to allow the user to login only if the sub_location_id exists in user_locations table with active status.

Below are the table structure.

**Users Table**

```
id (PK, AI),
user_id (UQ),
password,
status, ("Y"=> Active, "N"=> Inactive)
//other fields
```

**User_Locations Table**

```
id (PK, AI),
user_id (FK),
location_id (FK),
sub_location_id (FK),
status ("Y"=> Active, "N"=> Inactive)
```

**Locations Table**

```
id (PK, AI),
location_id,
location_name
```

**Sub_Locations Table**

```
id (PK, AI),
location_id (FK),
sub_location_id,
sub_location_name
```

Comment: Best write your own authentication logic.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: I would consider using a package such as [Spatie Laravel Permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction) or [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/) for implementing [RBAC](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=role+based+access+control).

Comment: @user3532758 I hope this will work. I will check this and get back if I need any help.

Comment: @user3532758 own authentication logic is working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding custom authentication as like in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users